# Passing generic wildcard type to a method accepting generic type

Tags: java

I'm writing some basic storage engine abstraction logic, but because different storage system use differently formatted primary keys (like Long for mysql, ObjectId for mongo) I'm using generics for my DBA.

```
public interface StorageAdapter<T> {
    Optional<PlayerModel<T>> getPlayer(OfflinePlayer offlinePlayer);
}

public class MysqlStorageAdapter implements StorageAdapter<Long> {
     ...
}
```

My application never knows the details of what type the storage is using, and it essentially doesn't care because that data is only used by the database. So I'm using wildcards:

```
Optional<? extends PlayerModel<?>> optionalPlayerModel = MyApp.getInstance().getStorageAdapter()
            .getPlayer(player);
```

What I don't understand is what my method signatures need to look like for passing in the data later:

```
void logPlayerConnection(PlayerModel<T> playerModel) { ... }
```

The optional type is `? extends PlayerModel<?>` but a method I want to pass that value to is `PlayerModel<T>`. `PlayerModel` is the highest interface I can accept. My IDE tries to suggest making `PlayerModel<T> extend PlayerModel<T>` which obviously can't work.

I'm not sure how best to handle this.

EDIT: Here is the exact error when trying to pass the playerModel to the logPlayerConnection method:

```
java:35: error: incompatible types: PlayerModel<CAP#1> cannot be converted to PlayerModel<CAP#2>
                .logPlayerConnection(playerModel);
                                   ^
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
    CAP#2 extends Object from capture of ?
```

EDIT2: Here's a more complete breakdown of my objects:

```
public interface StorageAdapter<T> {
    Optional<PlayerModel<T>> getPlayer(OfflinePlayer offlinePlayer);

    void logPlayerConnection(PlayerModel<?> playerModel);
}

public interface PlayerModel<T> extends PrimaryKeyModel<T> {

}

public interface PrimaryKeyModel<T> {
    T getId();
}

public class SqlPlayerModel extends AbstractModel<Long> implements PlayerModel<Long> {
    
}

public abstract class AbstractModel<T> {
    protected final T id;

    public AbstractModel(T id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public T getId() {
        return id;
    }
}



// Use case:

PlayerModel<?> playerModel;
Optional<? extends PlayerModel<?>> optionalPlayerModel = storageAdapter.getPlayer();

if (optionalPlayerModel.isPresent()) {
    playerModel = optionalPlayerModel.get();
} else {
    playerModel = /* create logic here */
}

storageAdapter.logPlayerConnection(playerModel);
```

Comment: Why don't you use an interface ? I.e. `interface Payer {  long getId(); ... }; class DbPlayerModel<Long> implements Payer { ... } void logPlayerConnection(Payer payer)` In any case seems like you are re-inventing [Spring Data](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: I am. `public interface PlayerModel<T> extends PrimaryKeyModel<T>`  and `public class SqlPlayerModel extends AbstractModel<Long> implements PlayerModel<Long>`

Comment: The more relevant part of Victor's comment was "in any case seems like you are re-inventing Spring Data". You might want to consider using an existing library (not necessarily Spring) since this is a non-trivial problem that's already been solved well.

Comment: That link blended in with the name to me so I did overlook that aspect. I'll definitely look into that but my use case is a very small project, and even if just for my education I'd like to figure out how to handle this issue or maybe realize the error in my approach.

Comment: where is the `T` in `void logPlayerConnection(PlayerModel<T> playerModel)` coming from? The error is due to some other constraints based on your variable. also your error is on `registerPlayerJoin`. can you provide a minimal example that will fully reproduce the error?

Comment: sorry registerPlayerJoin is logPlayerConnection, I renamed it after grabbing the error. the T is from `StorageAdapter<T>` itself. Per the example the actual storage implementation defines it, so `MysqlStorageAdapter implements StorageAdapter<Long>`

Comment: Seems like I have to use `void logPlayerConnection(PlayerModel<?> playerModel)` in my interface for the error to go away. I've posted a more complete example of all my interfaces/objects. Because each storage engine uses different types for primary keys I want to keep that internal as much as possible, but my difficulty here is that when external code needs to query something *and* pass that result around, `?` and `T` don't mix.

Comment: Also, looking at spring data, they have hard-coded the primary key typed in their models. I don't see how they're abstracting that because I'd need a new model for each source. For example they use `private final @Id Long id;` in the `Person` example